# where to find the slides in the drupal site

Tags: drupal-7

We have been given a site xyz.com, in which the home page has images sliding. We dont know whether it is a block (or) view.

Now our site is migrated to abc.com.The home page is not showing the images sliding. 
When i did inspect element images are there. But they are not loaded since the javascript used has been given wrong link. the div has id "slides". javascript slides.min.jquery.js is used. I could not see those slide in blocks or views.

Please tell me where can i find that so that i can change the javascript link.

Please help.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more context. Please at least post a link to the site.

Comment: hm. i cannot give the link to site because  need to use firewalker. I cannot give those firewalker details.Without which it is impossible to open the link to site. i have searched block and views but nowhere i cannot find the code.

Comment: Sounds like your slides.min.jquery.js isn't being loaded. If you click the link in the source code to the js file does it open in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Problem is images url is given wrong and we are using our own theme . so changed the urls in sites/all/themes/our theme folder/templates/page.tpl.php. and it worked fine.